# How can you the movement speed of an object in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

So I was messing with pygame, the thing is I have a ball whereas when I move this ball I want it to leave fading shadow trails but the thing is it happens to fast where the "shadow trail" is barely visible.

Adjusting the "clock.tick()" quite solves this issue but I only want that specific object, in this case the ball to be the only one that slows down. I don't necessarily need to decrease the speed but I figured its the thing that I can do to make my fading shadow trails visible. Here's the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

game_over = False
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
screen_size = (500, 500)
ball_x, ball_y = 261.5, 261.5
post_xa, post_ya, post_xb, post_yb = 261.5, 261.5, 261.5, 261.5
line = []
ival = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Keeping it Small and Simple")

for x, y in zip(range(250, -1, -5), range(0, 250, 5)):
    line.append([y, 0, 0, x])
for x, y in zip(range(0, 250, 5), range(250, 500, 5)):
    line.append([500, x, y, 0])
for x, y in zip(range(500, 250, -5), range(250, 500, 5)):
    line.append([500, y, x, 500])
for x, y in zip(range(250, -1, -5), range(500, 250, -5)):
    line.append([0, y, x, 500])

while not game_over:
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over = True

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        ball_y -= 8
        post_ya -= 8    
    if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        ball_y += 8
        post_ya += 8
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        ball_x -= 8
        post_xa -= 8
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        ball_x += 8
        post_xa += 8

#Code for the shadow
    colorb = 0
    for i in range(8):
        colors = colorb, colorb, colorb
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (colors), (int(post_xb), int(post_yb)), int(21.5))
        colorb += 30
        if post_xa > post_xb:
            post_xb += 1
        if post_xa < post_xb:
            post_xb -= 1
        if post_ya > post_yb:
            post_yb += 1
        if post_ya < post_yb:
            post_yb -= 1

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, (int(ball_x), int(ball_y)), int(21.5))

# background effect
    col = 0
    cur = ival   
    for i in range (40):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[cur]
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (col,col,col), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), 2)

        cur += 1
        if cur >= len(line):
            cur = 0
        col += 240 / 40 

    ival += 1
    if ival >= len(line):
        ival = 0

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit()
```

Here's a rough example of it:
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DzTyqcXhitY/maxresdefault.jpg
whereas the ball is the darkest figure and then it leaves lighter ones as it moves(trails) that eventually disappears if no movement happens.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`clock.tick(40)` simply set a FPS limit to your game.

Though not being clear, I think that by saying "background effect" you mean the speed of your main loop which is defined by `clock.tick`. So instead of changing `40` to other values, you can simply decrease the pixels of each move to lower the speed of your moving object.

Comment: The background effect that I'm talking about is the animation that happens on the screen, the line animation on the side, I want it to stay as fast as it is. No matter how much I decrease or increase the movement of my ball, the shadow is still way too fast that it is barely visible. I want my ball effect to work as my animation whereas as my ball moves it leave a white to black gradient trails, fairly similar to my background effect where think of the lightest line as the ball and the fading lines is the trails it leaves. 

Changing the ball's color make the "trails" a bit more visible.

Comment: It looks like you need to go into the code for the "ball/shadow" and define a speed for it like you did for the background effect.